# how to update url in shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

Right now I have `p("Please click", a("here", href = URL ))` inside the `UI` section of shiny app where URL is simple variable whose value is not fixed.
Now I am performing some operations inside the `server` section & eventually, I want to update my URL variable.
Can anybody tell me how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [reactive value](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.3.0/reactiveVal.html). You can initialize it to whatever value you want it to have at the beginning:

```
URL <- reactiveVal("www.website.com")
```

And then you can have it automatically update depending on other stuff that the user changes:

```
observeEvent(input$some_input, {
  newURL <- paste0(URL(), "/some_page")    
  URL(newURL)             
})
```

Notice that when you need the value of `URL`, you have to call it as a function. To then change this within the UI, we need to make the link a reactive UI output:

```
output$link <- renderUI({
  a("here", href = URL())
})
```

And then in your `ui.R`:

```
p("Please click", htmlOutput("link", inline = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but it seems like there is something wrong. How I can call the URL function from the UI component, as I need to initialize the URL inside the server. It's showing me the error ```could not find function "URL"```

Comment: your solution looks good & gives no error, but it is not working. when I am clicking the link, it's simply showing "Not Found".

Comment: So sorry - there were some typos. Fixed them, and tried it out. It should work now...